# How to split a Ruby array into a certain number of smaller arrays?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have a large Ruby array that I would split into smaller arrays. I don't care about how many items are in each array, rather, I care about specifying how many arrays I will end up with. I will be displaying the items in columns. For example, how can I split the array into two, or three smaller arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Rails (you don't say) you could use `in_groups`.

```
%w(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10).in_groups(3) {|group| p group}
["1", "2", "3", "4"]
["5", "6", "7", nil]
["8", "9", "10", nil]
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-in_groups

Or, if not Rails, just take the source for that method...

Comment: Ah, this is actually the functionality that I want. Except that I don't want to pad with `nil`. The syntax that I used is `in_groups(3, false)`

Answer (score 2):

Without Rails, I'd use `each_slice`:

```
2.0.0p247 :006 > arr = %w(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
 => ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"] 

2.0.0p247 :007 > n = 3  # how many arrays you want
 => 3

2.0.0p247 :009 > arr.each_slice((arr.size/n.to_f).ceil) {|slice| p slice };nil
["1", "2", "3", "4"]
["5", "6", "7", "8"]
["9", "10"]
 => nil
```

Comment: That's actually the opposite of what I want. `each_slice` is for when you need to specify a length for each array. I suppose I could do what I want with `each_slice(myarray.count / 3)`

Comment: See my update.  I updated my answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = (1..10).to_a
nsublists = 3
sublists = []
list.each_slice((list.size.to_f/nsublists).ceil) { |slice| sublists << slice }

sublists # => [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10]]
```